# How far above sea level can you get on the equator?

Tags: geography

Quite simply what is the highest point above sea level that is right on the equator, I figured it would be a mountain in the Ecuadorian Andes but the Kenyan highlands look to be a likely candidate as well. I've tried to find it but I simply can't find a map that has the equator and the altitude in a highly accurate format and resolution anywhere.

Comment: I assume you mean on exactly the 0° latitude line. Otherwise it would be Chimborazo which is 1° 28' N.

Comment: If you want to put in the work,  you can download and view a free DEM at https://gisgeography.com/free-global-dem-data-sources/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would assume that's the highest point on the equator you talking about, so The highest point on the Equator is at the elevation of 4,690 metres (15,387 ft), at 0°0′0″N 77°59′31″W, found on the southern slopes of [Volcán Cayambe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayambe_(volcano)) [summit 5,790 metres (18,996 ft)] in Ecuador. This is slightly above the snow line and is the only place on the Equator where snow lies on the ground.

Answer (score 1):

You're right about Mount Kenya, which is more or less on the equator and is about 5,000 metres above sea level. Mount Kinabalu in northern Borneo (Malaysia) is also on the equator, but only 4,000 metres high. Kilimanjaro, next door to Kenya in Tanzania, is about 6,ooo metres, but further from the equator than Mount Kenya